# sed multiline pattern buffer flush on last line - normal behaviour?

Tags: regex, sed

Consider this input file.

```
# cat test.txt
some other stuff
some more other stuff
first line
second thingy
third whatsit
fourth oojiflop
fifth item
sixth widget
this is the
end of file
```

Running this one liner works just as I wanted (multiple sed commands as I created this on OSX). It deletes all lines between "first line" and "fifth item" inclusive, but only if the "fifth item" appears.

```
sed -e '/^first line/{' -e ':no' -e '$!{N' -e '/fifth item$/ b y' -e 'b no' -e ':y' -e 'd;};}' test.txt
```

I was concerned that should the "fifth item" pattern not be matched in the lines following the "first line", then it would not print any lines subsequent to the "first line". But it does. And it seems to work in GNU flavours as well as BSD/OSX.

So - if I run

```
sed -e '/^first line/{' -e ':no' -e '$!{N' -e '/xxxxxxx$/ b y' -e 'b no' -e ':y' -e 'd;};}' test.txt
```

then, when it reaches ^first line it will start to fill up the pattern buffer using the 'N' command. It will continue, looking for xxxxxxx until it hits the EOF, and the $! test fails. At this point, the execution returns from the outer braces, and before terminating, sed appears to dump the entire pattern buffer to std out.

I wasn't aware of this behaviour - my question is whether this is normal behaviour and where it is documented (the fact that the whole pattern buffer got dumped when the $! test failed)

Comment: What is the intended behavior you're looking for, exactly?

Comment: `sed` defaults to printing the pattern space unless you use `-n`.

Comment: There comes a point at which `sed -f script.sed` is more sensible than squishing everything into multiple `-e` options on a single line. I think your scripts have probably reached that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/^first line/{' -e ':no' -e '$!{N;/fifth item$/ b y' -e 'b no' -e ':y' -e 'd' -e '}' -e '}' test.txt
```

- The last `;};}` is not understand by sed, separe brace with several `-e` instead of `;` and it should in this case
- I reduced your version by concatenate `/fifth...` with previous expression.

Another way for a OneLiner like is to use the CTRL+V+J instead of return/newline at promt time in shell (does not do the same in vi where it add a real new line)

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all multiline match if your reach end-of-file whenever last line match or not your search expression.

```
/^first line/ {
  :no
  $ {
    d
  }
  $! {
   N
   /xxxxxxx$/ b y
   b no
   :y
   d
  }
}
```

Comment: This may be refactored so: `/^first line/{:a;$d;N;/xxxxxxx$/d;ba}` if you so wish replace `;` by newlines. The point is, if you check for end-of-file and delete on success then any commands following will only be reached if it is not end-of-file. Likewise on matching the final string.